# Password Validation Assistance

Tags: javascript

I am trying to validate password in JS; the password should be not more than 8 characters, it should match, and it should notify users of error before they click submit on the form.

*Note: my form returns null when checking the console, what could be the problem?I have other JS code on the page as well, not just the password one.*

I did this which doesn't seem to work:

```
var password1 = document.getElementById("pwd1");
var password2 = document.getElementById("pwd2");

var passwordValidity = function() {

if (password1.value.length >= 8 != password2.value.length >= 8) {
    password1.innerHTML="Oops! Passwords must be at least 8 characters!";
    password1.style.background="red";
  } else {
        pwd2Hint.innerHTML =" Your passwords don't match";  
    }

};  

password1.addEventListener("keyup", passwordValidity, false);
password2.addEventListener("keyup", passwordValidity, false);

var form = document.getElementById("hw4Form");

form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        passwordValidity();
        event.preventDefault();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. Some of the logic in `passwordValidity` is a bit off.
2. You're not having `passwordValidity` tell its caller what happened (e.g., it needs to return something).

Fixing 1:

This is not doing what the code expects it to do:

```
if (password1.value.length >= 8 != password2.value.length >= 8) {
```

That's only going to be true when one of the password fields has a length less than 8 and the other has a length greater than or equal to 8.

You've tried to combine two things there which can't be combined. Instead:

```
if (password1.value.length < 8) {
    // ...show must be at least 8 error...
} else if (password1.value != password2.value) {
    // ...show "they don't match" error
} else {
    // All okay
}
```

Fixing 2: Just have it return a flag (and probably change its name to make clear that it does). Combining with the above:

```
var isPasswordValid = function() {
    var valid = false;

    if (password1.value.length < 8) {
        password1.innerHTML = "Oops! Passwords must be at least 8 characters!";
    } else if (password1.value != password2.value) {
        pwd2Hint.innerHTML =" Your passwords don't match";
    } else {
        // All okay
        pwd2Hint.innerHTML = "";
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
};
```

Then using it:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    if (!isPasswordValid()) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
    }
}, false);
```

---

Side note: I wouldn't replace `password1`'s value when the password is too short. For one thing, typically it would be a `type="password"` field and showing placeholders for characters rather than being readable, and for another, that's a very unusual thing to do which will surprise users with the normal expectation that you haven't done that. Either leave it or clear it, and have another hint field like you do for `password2` for showing the error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation. I had my form wrapped with a window.onload function; then it gave the same error saying that my form is null. When I deleted the onload function, I got the message that "TypeError: password1 is null". I need to say that no other function seem to work on my form. What would it be that I am doing worng?

Comment: @Reem: Sounds like your `script` tag is probably in the wrong place. Script code runs as soon as the `script` tag is encountered, so if the `script` tag is *above* the HTML for the elements, they won't exist when you run `getElementById` and it'll return `null`. Unless you have a reason to do something else, put your `script` tags at the end of the HTML, just before the closing `</body>` tag. More: [**](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was so helpful. I found out that I using getElementById for a name tag! $ / My bad!

Answer (score 0):

I would change the `passwordValidity` function to return true or false and then change the submit to

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  return passwordValidity();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your approach. Think it like that:

- When do you want this comparison to be performed?
  If you perform the validation as soon as the first field is submitted, the second field won't be completed for sure. I would set both fields as required, and perform the validation on blur of the second field.
- Fix the function's conditions:

`if (password1.value.length >= 8 != password2.value.length >= 8) {`
Change `!=` to `&&`, you need an AND operator, and make sure both of conditions check for the opposite. Also consider checking the minimum length.

The way this function is written, both `if` and `else` are treated as errors. Put an `else if` for the second error, and an `else` for the successful case.

- Return a true or false from your conditions, so the submit event listener can know what happened during validation.